# BmpBitmapEncoder сохранение в 24 битном формате

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, bitmap, bmp

```
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = new Uri(dialog.FileName);
src.EndInit();
BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src));
                
byte[] data;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     encoder.Save(ms);
     data = ms.ToArray();
}
MainImage.Source = src;
File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\gtwg.bmp", data);
```

есть вот такой код, в wpf, выводит изображение и сохраняет его в bmp. Но bmp сохраняется в 32-ух битном формате, как можно сохранять в 24х битном?

Comment: [`FormatConvertedBitmap`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap?view=netframework-4.8) вас спасет. И вам здесь вообще не нужен `MemoryStream` пишите сразу в файл, кучу памяти сэкономите `using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"D:\gtwg.bmp")) { encoder.Save(fs); }` - всё.

Comment: Мне необходимо иметь массив байт в bmp формате 24 битной кодировки, для дальнейшей обработки, изображения, конечной целью является именно работа с таким форматом, запись в конце в файл, я использовал чтобы просто проверить как записался файл. Не могли бы вы привести пример работы FormatConvertedBitmap? Не совсем понимаю как он работает даже прочитав о нём на мсдне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, я разобрался FormatConvertedBitmap, решил мою проблему.

```
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = new Uri(dialog.FileName);
src.EndInit();
BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
FormatConvertedBitmap fcb = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
                
fcb.BeginInit();
fcb.Source = src;
fcb.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Bgr24;
fcb.EndInit();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(fcb));
byte[] data;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     encoder.Save(ms);
     data = ms.ToArray();
}
MainImage.Source = src;
File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\gtwg.bmp", data);
```